# How can I pin an UIImageView to the top without stretching it?

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard

I'm trying to pin an image to the top of the screen but I keep getting an extra white extra space at the top. I tried to pin the image relative to the superview instead of the save area but It didn’t work.

image's constraints relative to superview

[image: image's constraints relative to superview]

changing the image's content mode to Scale To Fill solves the issue but it stretches the image.

After changing the image's content  mode

[image: After changing the image's content mode]

Comment: What happens if you set the content mode to `Top`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the `contentMode` of the UIImageView to either `.scaleAspectFit` or `.scaleAspectFill`, whatever fits best your needs.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it didn’t work. the scaleAspectFill stretched the image.

Comment: This is weird, it shouldn't stretch the image,. It might be just a bug in the storyboard, have you tried it on device or simulator?

Comment: You could try constraining the height of the UIImageView to it's width with the aspect ratio matching the images ones. That way you can make sure, that the UIImageView is never higher than the Image itself and there shouldn't be any gap at the top.